# How to create comma separated list from multiple select elements Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form of dynamically created single option select elements. What I need to do is create a list of all of the selected indexes of these elements, separated by a comma. I'm using

```js
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
```

to grab a node list (whatever one of those is, I'm guessing like an array?) of all of the select elements, and I know about .selectedindex, but I'm stuck from there.

I would like to get an output like:

3,4,6,1

I want to use this data in a query string to do some magic.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 var counterid = counter;
 var newdivid = "dynamic-div-"+counterid;
 newdiv.setAttribute("id", newdivid);
 oldelement = document.getElementById('cat-drop-id');
 newelement = oldelement.cloneNode(true);
 newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><select name='cat' id='cat-dropdown-id" + counterid + "' class='som-changecat-category-dropdown'>" + newelement.innerHTML + "</select><input type='button' id='remove-button-id" + counterid + "' value='Remove DUMMY' onclick='removeDummy(this.id);' /><br><br>";

 document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
 counter++;
}

function removeDummy(elementtoremove) {
 var elem = document.getElementById(elementtoremove);
 elem.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem.parentNode);
 return false;
}
```

```html
 <form action="?page=test-options-page&something=0" method="POST">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
  <select name="cat" id="cat-drop-id" class="som-changecat-category-dropdown">
   <option value="-1">Select category</option>
   <option class="level-0" value="1">test</option>
   <option class="level-0" value="2">test2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add another dropdown" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: can you please post your html code

Comment: Provide a full code - HTML, JS with creation

Comment: Done. I'm working in WordPress, the PHP call grabs a dropdown box list, which I can clone/remove clone at will. Some code is pseudo, this is functionality testing.

Comment: Removed the php call and added the raw select element HTML. Snippet works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to convert nodeList to array.
and you can get more info about it here: https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array

below is the full working code.

notice the extra `button` i add and `getValue()` method =)

```
<form action="?page=test-options-page&something=0" method="POST">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <select name="cat" id="cat-drop-id" class="som-changecat-category-dropdown">
      <option value="-1">Select category</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="1">test</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="2">test2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add another dropdown" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <button onClick="getValue(event)">get comma seperated value</button>
</form>

<script>

  var counter = 1;
  function addInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var counterid = counter;
    var newdivid = "dynamic-div-"+counterid;
    newdiv.setAttribute("id", newdivid);
    oldelement = document.getElementById('cat-drop-id');
    newelement = oldelement.cloneNode(true);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><select name='cat' id='cat-dropdown-id" + counterid + "' class='som-changecat-category-dropdown'>" + newelement.innerHTML + "</select><input type='button' id='remove-button-id" + counterid + "' value='Remove DUMMY' onclick='removeDummy(this.id);' /><br><br>";

    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
  }

function removeDummy(elementtoremove) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elementtoremove);
  elem.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem.parentNode);
  return false;
}

function getValue(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // all select element.
  var selects = document.getElementById('dynamicInput').querySelectorAll('select');

  // convert nodeList to array
  var selectsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects)

  // now you can use Array.prototype.*
  var result = selectsArray.map(select => {
    return select.value;
  }).join(',');

  // do what ever you want with `result` now.
  console.log(result);

  return result;
}


</script>
```

Comment: Just want to mention that using `.slice` to convert node lists to arrays may not work in older browsers like IE8. But I guess we can leave this one behind with a smile. :)

Comment: bitsMix there's an error with the code in internet explorer. It says there's a syntax error in this:   var result = selectsArray.map(select => {
    return select.value;
  }).join(','); I think it's pointing to the => symbol. Can you help? It prevents the whole thing from working.

Comment: Problem solved. Had to make it a function line, replace select =>, with function(select)

Comment: it's "arrow function" as a shorter syntax for function. introduced in ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

As `.selectedOptions` is still isn’t safe to go with there is nothing more than to iterate the options of each select and get the selected ones. Try something like:

```js
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('som-changecat-category-dropdown');
var values = {}, select, id, optionValues;
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  select = selects[i];
  id = select.id;
  optionValues = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < select.options.length; j++) {  
    var option = select.options[j];
    if (option.selected) optionValues.push(option.value);
  }
  values[select.id] = optionValues.join(',');
}
// gives you an object with the selects’ ids as keys 
//and the komma separated values as value
document.write(JSON.stringify(values));
```

```html
<form action="?page=test-options-page&something=0" method="POST">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <select multiple id="cat-dropdown-1" class="som-changecat-category-dropdown">
     <option value="1" selected>bli</option>
     <option value="2">bla</option>
     <option value="3" selected>blu</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple id="cat-dropdown-2" class="som-changecat-category-dropdown">
     <option value="4">blimm</option>
     <option value="5" selected>blamm</option>
     <option value="6" selected>blumm</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add another dropdown" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

You could make this work to collect all the form elements’ values and use the resulting object as a base for creating your query string.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this generates output I can work with. However, the other answer creates the list as needed, so selected that as the answer.